# The name 'Entities' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, entity-component-system

```
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using Unity.Entities;
   
 public class AttributesGenerationSystem : ComponentSystem
 {
     private static EntityManager entityManager;
   
     [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.BeforeSceneLoad)]
     public static void Initialize()
     {
         entityManager = World.Active.GetOrCreateManager<EntityManager>();
     }
     protected override void OnUpdate()
     {
         Entities.ForEach();
     }
 }
```

I know I haven't entered parameters yet for Entities.ForEach(); — that’s not my issue. I get the error message;

"The name 'Entities' does not exist in the current context"

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Not knowing much about Unity, `Entities` is a namespace, not an object. You can't iterate over a namespace. Check the Unity documentation for how to use objects in the Entities namespace correctly.

Comment: Actually, I looked at the documentation, and Entities.ForEach is a defined function in the namespace. Apologies.

Comment: Update -- I have an idea as to what might be the problem. ECS is part of Unity DOTS, which is very experimental and getting updated all the time. They deprecate important parts of it all the time -- this has given me severe issues following tutorials of even as little as a few months back.

Comment: It also looks like the Jobs system -- another system that's part of DOTS -- has a function -- IJobForEach<> -- that seems to do the same exact thing that Entities.ForEach() was trying to do, only in a more complicated yet admittedly more optomized way. I'm going to try to figure out the job system tomorrow as well as IJobForEach specifically tomorrow.

Comment: I thought I would just keep some documentation of the thought process here (I think that's how these forums are supposed to work?) Thanks for all the help I've received already -- it helped a ton to see that I'm not just missing something obvious and that this is in fact a question that can potentially be helpful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I extended JobComponentSystem and used Unity's job system instead of what appears to be a deprecated Entities.ForEach() method. And then I tried using Unity 2019.3 (was using 2018.4 before), and it all fell apart. Got tons of error messages and apparently JobComponentSystem is now deprecated too? So I've now decided I'm going to wait for the DOTS team to finish this thing up, because I'm working on a big project, and this lack of documentation combined with a constantly changing library is making my head hurt.

TL;DR: No one will ever read this again because Unity DOTS will be unrecognizable pretty soon and these kinds of problems will probably not exist.